# In Databricks, how do I determine which columns changed from a change data capture feed?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, change-data-capture

In my example, I have a pre/post after an update in my CDF. Is there a way to determine by an external_id per each microbatch, which columns have changed?

| external_id | subscribe_status | subscribe_dt | end_sub_dt | _change_type | _commit_version | _commit_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ryan | inactive | 2023-01-01 | 2023-12-05 | update_postimage | 3 | 2023-12-05T22:47:06.000+00:00 |
| ryan | active | 2023-01-01 | NA | update_preimage | 3 | 2023-12-05T22:47:06.000+00:00 |